# How do you change the window title line text in Vim?

Tags: vim-windows, statusline

How do I change where is says `[No Name]` or where it says `gibbersh-letters-of-base64` to a text of my choosing?

[image: vim9 two panels]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are buffer names (in case of `[No Name]` buffer has no name).

`:h :file_f` as in

```
:file my new name instead of base64 gibberish
```

would change buffer name to `my new name instead of base64 gibberish`.

Note that there might be "subtle" things under the hood you might not expect to happen, e.g. `:file some_existing_file_in_cwd`.